# React JS Conditional Update State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which updates state, I only want this to work based on the following indexY positions.

```
if indexY is === 0 &&
if indexY is === 5 &&
if indexY is === 10
```

here is my fucnction:

```
if(this.state.indexY > 0){
      if(targetX < 0 || targetX > actionLength) {
        return;
      } else {
        this.setState({
          indexX: targetX,
          transform,
        });
      }
    }
```

Please note that if I use `if(this.state.indexY === 0)` this does not work - I don't understand why? It only works if I use what is currently there `if(this.state.indexY > 0)`

Comment: You need to use `||` (logical OR), since `indexY` cannot equal 0 and 5 at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using && in your expression. indexY cannot be 0, 5 and 10 in the same time. Use || instead